# How can you add client-specific information to a product of an order in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am trying to implement an e-commerce site where the client can pick the t-shirt he wants to buy. And then he may choose one of the available patterns to print it into that t-shirt. Or he can provide a text that he wants imprinted on that t-shirt.

The problem is that I am not quite sure how would I take this information from the client and append it to the product of the order on checkout. I was thinking of using wp_ajax to get the chosen pattern/text from the client, but I am not quite sure how would I link that information to the right product + user combo.

I am not very experienced in the plugin, so I am having a little trouble with finding a way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your product as a variable product. Add an attribute `design` and let the user choose which design they want to order.

This solves your design picking issue.

Next -> (How to get text from the user.)

You can use this tutorial https://pluginrepublic.com/woocommerce-custom-fields/ which explains how to add custom fields to your product.

How to show it on frontend and eventually add that value in your order meta.

Product screenshot:
[image]

There are plugins as well which will can help you add custom fields for a product.

Found this which should do the job for getting the text data in order :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-product-addons/